# Why did the thread pool size increase in this case?

Tags: .net, async-await, concurrency, threadpool

I was following an old post by Stephen Toub to force a Console App to run an async function using just the main thread. I was successful in doing that, but by the end, I noticed that the ThreadPool size still got increased. Hoping to get some input.

(See code and link to Stephen's post below).

I'm wondering what caused the thread pool to allocate new threads. Does `Task.Delay` always cause such a thing? When I ran the program (.NET 6, MacOS), the result showed:

```
$ dotnet ./bin/Debug/net6.0/publish/con.dll
ThreadCount: 0
ThreadCount went from 0 to 2 at i=0
ThreadCount went from 2 to 3 at i=91
[1, 1000]
Completing on 1
ThreadCount: 3

$ dotnet ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/con.dll
ThreadCount: 0
ThreadCount went from 0 to 2 at i=0
ThreadCount went from 2 to 3 at i=401
[1, 1000]
Completing on 1
ThreadCount: 3
```

Note that in my Program.cs, I force the last `Complete()` call to be scheduled on the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. This is different from the blog post, which used `TaskScheduler.Default`. I found that using default, the `Complete()` call as triggered in the thread pool, which is expected.

Pasting the code here inline:

```cs
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

// Example from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/
internal class Program
{
    private sealed class SingleThreadSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
    {

        private readonly BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object?>> m_queue = new();

        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object? state)
        {
            m_queue.Add(new KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object?>(d, state));
        }

        public void RunOnCurrentThread()
        {
            KeyValuePair<SendOrPostCallback, object?> workItem;
            while (m_queue.TryTake(out workItem, Timeout.Infinite))
            {
                workItem.Key(workItem.Value);
            }
        }

        public void Complete()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Completing on {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            m_queue.CompleteAdding();
        }

        public static void Run(Func<Task> func)
        {
            var syncCtx = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext();
            var prevCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            try
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);
                var t = func();

                t.ContinueWith(
                    delegate { syncCtx.Complete(); },
                    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                syncCtx.RunOnCurrentThread();
                t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            finally
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(prevCtx);
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            int count;

            d[id] = d.TryGetValue(id, out count) ? count + 1 : 1;

            var threadCount = ThreadPool.ThreadCount;
            await Task.Delay(1);
            if (ThreadPool.ThreadCount != threadCount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ThreadCount went from {threadCount} to {ThreadPool.ThreadCount} at i={i}");
            }
        }

        foreach (var pair in d) Console.WriteLine(pair);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ThreadCount: {ThreadPool.ThreadCount}");
        SingleThreadSynchronizationContext.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
        Console.WriteLine($"ThreadCount: {ThreadPool.ThreadCount}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this in Debug or Release configuration?

Comment: Hey @PauloMorgado, I updated the post—but the results are similar for both Debug and Release configuration.

Comment: Use dotnet-trace or PerfView to capture a trace and you'll find out what's adding the threads.